# blender modifier that makes an object invisible, but also blocks the objects that WOULD HAVE BEEN behind the previous object

Tags: modifiers, masking

Okay, I know that's long winded, but hear me out.

say, I have this circle in 3d:
[image]

but behind it there's a star (made the original circle transparent):
[image]

is there a modifier that, instead of the following: remove circle > star becomes fully visible,
it instead does: remove circle > star becomes invisible (under the conditions you are not facing the star)

basically, so that anything the the sphere WOULD be covering from the angle of the camera, it is not. then if you move the camera, different parts become invisible/visible, and so on.

I hope this made ANY SENSE